# How to update a label when user touch the mapkit pin annotation?

Tags: ios, mapkit

I have made a map and arrange a pin coming from json as array but when i touch pin,a label in the same viewcontroller's view will be updated.How?
Do these delegates  I have to use:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didDeselectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
```

How??
Edit:
Thanx for reply got the solution it was delegate.

Comment: yes use delegate to update label text

Comment: but confused how to start...any suggestion or example code would be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to the site. If any of the answers helped you then please inform the community by voting up. This will let others know that you have resolved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

MKAnnotationView just shows the contents of the associated MKAnnotation. You should update either the title or subtitle of the annotation itself.

Answer (score 0):

you have to implement didSelectAnnotationView like this :

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
    {
          if (![view.annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) { //test that if the annotation that you touched is not the user location (if you did showsUserLocation = YES)
            //change your label here
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

rather then changing the label beeter UI is to display a view as user click on the annotation:
You can refer to this 2 links for that:

1. [Multirow popover view](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/multirowcalloutannotationview)
2. [custom view](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/custom-map-annotation)